# Simple button action

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm using the code below to determine whether or not the page should show images or not.  The button "works" sometimes, but other times it will take 2 or 3 clicks in order for the images to display.

Am I missing something?

```
    Private Sub btnViewAll_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnViewAll.Click
    If Session("fullPage") IsNot Nothing Then
        If CInt(Session("fullPage")) = 0 Then
            Session("fullPage") = 1
        Else
            Session("fullPage") = 0
        End If
    Else
        Session("fullPage") = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

I check for the session here:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvFolders.RowDataBound

    If CInt(Session("fullPage")) = 1 Then
      ...load images....
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Which method is your code in that checks Session("showImages")? The _Click event fires off all the other normal Page Load events, etc, so you may not have everything in the proper order.

Comment: I think @ShawnSteward is on the right track, you should review the asp.net page lifecycle to ensure that you are setting and consuming the session during an appropriate state: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: thanks for the link.  I am checking for the session in a gridviews RowDataBoundEvent...this is where I display images...

Comment: I updated my question with more relevant code...

Comment: +1 A useful question highlighting a common, very subtle logic error which has felled many a new (or even experienced) ASP.NET programmer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you are setting your Session variable *after* you have referenced it.

For example, if you are using the variable in the Page_Load, then on the first click the value will be `False` by default (causing you to not render the images). After the Page_Load event has finished,  the click event handler will fire, setting the session variable to `True`. But, since Page_Load has already finished, you will not see the images until after Page_Load is called again (on the second postback).

This is only one example of what can happen when you are not paying close attention to the page life cycle. Since we can't see your code, it's impossible to know exactly where the logic error is occurring.

See the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information about the order of events.

---

**EDIT**
You may need to move some of your logic from the Page_Load to the [Page_LoadComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event. LoadComplete is usually the best place to do data binding, etc, after you have processed your control events.

*To answer your question in the comments below, the session handling is actually in the appropriate place. I can't see where you are calling `GridView1.DataBind()`, but most likely it is that code which is not in the correct place. Move the `DataBind` call to the LoadComplete page event, and you should be set.*

Comment: I am only setting the session in the onClick event code of my button.

Comment: Ok I've updated my code to reflect for an empty session.  But it still  sometimes requires multiple clicks

Comment: But you still have the problem that `GridView1_RowDataBound` may be called before `btnViewAll_Click` depending on when you call `GridView1.DataBind()`

Comment: But isn't the code within btnViewAll_Click executed whenever you click on the button?  So it would be executed first, right?

Comment: No... you are used to working with WinForms. Please read the linked article concerning the ASP.NET Page Lifecycle. The button events occur only after page events, etc. The click event would be filed under "Postback event handling"

Comment: Ok, I see that now.  So I am guessing that RowDataBound is being called before the Click event code.  If that is so, then where in the code is the best place to put the session handling?  page load?

Comment: @999cm999 - Seriously, read the article. It explains it better than I could.